# php - insert new folders into a string containing file paths

Tags: php, str-replace

Is it possible to use php to search a string for a file path pattern and then insert a new folder at a specified point?

```
<?php
$string = '<ul>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-a/file-a.htm">Link Text a</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-b/file-b.htm">Link Text b</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-c/file-c.htm">Link Text c</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-d/file-d.htm">Link Text d</a></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

I don’t know in advance what folders-a,b,c,d or files-a,b,c,d will be called so I don’t see how I can use str_replace. I want in each case to insert a new folder before the file so that the outcome would look like this (the new-folder would have the same name in each case):

```
<?php
$string = '<ul>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-a/new-folder/file-a.htm">Link Text a</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-b/new-folder/file-b.htm">Link Text b</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-c/new-folder/file-c.htm">Link Text c</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-d/new-folder/file-d.htm">Link Text d</a></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: I am confused what you are doing. Are you trying to make a dynamic pages and make it to a seo friendly url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming your HTML is always well formed** this could work for you:

```
$string = '<ul>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-a/file-a.htm">Link Text a</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-b/file-b.htm">Link Text b</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-c/file-c.htm">Link Text c</a></li>
<li><a href="/folder1/folder-d/file-d.htm">Link Text d</a></li>
</ul>';

$newString = preg_replace_callback(
  '/href="(.*?)"/i',
  function($matches) {
    return 'href="'.dirname($matches[1]).'/new-folder/'.basename($matches[1]).'"';
  },
  $string
);

echo $newString;
```

It is, as many people here will emphatically tell you, not a good idea to parse HTML with regex unless you **know** it to be well formed.

Comment: Thank you very much DaveRandom, it does work fine. I am expecting that folder1 will be dropped at some point in the future. How would I need to modify it if the file paths become href="/folder-a/file-a.htm etc?

Comment: Well you could `substr()` it off, or any number of other things. Inside the callback function, `$matches[1]` contains the file path inside the `href` attribute, so you can manipulate that however you want - for example, you could `explode()` it by `/` and use functions like `array_shift()` to manipulate it, then `implode()` it again. As long as the callback returns a full `href="/file/path"` attribute string, the code that you use to create the string is irrelevant.

Comment: Dave thanks, that's a bit beyond my level at the moment. I've just tested without a folder1 in the path using the code you provided and it still works correctly. Maybe I won't need to change anything?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, the `/folder1` section would disappear from the input HTML itself, rather than you would have to manually remove it? Well in that case no, you wouldn't have to change anything. The way this code works is by getting the `dirname()` of the file, which is basically everything before the last `/`, slotting in your `/new-folder/` string and then appending the `basename()`, which is everything after the last `/`. So the actual path in the HTML is irrelevant, it will simply insert `/new-folder/` as the last path component before the file name.