# Replace portion of url filepath found in HTML page text

Tags: php, regex, url, path, preg-replace

Given some urls inside an html page, I want to replace some urls as below:

Example url: `https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/article1`
From that one I want to replace the text that is between `/cost-center/` and the last part of the url (`article1`) with the another text (`test`)

That means the above url would be converted to: `https://example.com/cost-center/test/article1`.

In my case there can be more parts after `/cost-center/` and the url can end with a slash or can be inside quotes as in the examples below:

```
https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-two/article-3/
https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-three/article-4
https://example.com/cost-center/sub-1/sub-two/sub-three/article-5/
'https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-two/article-3/'
'https://example.com/cost-center/sub-1/sub-two/sub-three/article-5'
"https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-three/article-4"
"https://example.com/cost-center/sub-1/sub-two/sub-three/article-5/"
```

those would be replaced as below:

```
https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-3/
https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-4
https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-5/
'https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-3/'
'https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-5'
"https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-4"
"https://example.com/cost-center/test/article-5/"
```

For now let's assume that the url will have **at least one** and **at most three**  parts after the `/cost-center/`;

e.g. `https://example.com/cost-center/sub-1/sub-two/sub-three/article-5/`

So basically I want to replace some parts of it while keeping the last part.

I have trying using a numerours regexes such as:

```php
preg_replace('~https://example.com/cost-center/[^/]+/([^/]+)~', 'https://example.com/cost-center/test/$1', $url);

preg_replace('/(["\']?)(https:\/\/[^\/]+\/)([^\/]+)(\/[^"\s]*)?/', '$1$2test$4$1', $url);
```

I have also tried using splitting the url with `explode` and parsing it manually piece by piece, but it turned out very complicated and ugly.

The `ChatGPT` also has no good results.

Comment: Related content: [php - insert new folders into a string containing file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9924297/2943403)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried the following:
The regex capture 3 groups:

1. The beginning of the url up to `/cost-center/`
2. Everything between `/cost-center/` and the last part of the url
3. The last part of the url which can end with a slash or not

```php
$pattern = '/(https:\/\/example.com\/cost-center\/)(.*?)([^\/]+\/?$)/';
$replacement = '$1test/$3';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $url);
```

In the replacement string, you keep the fist and third group `($1 and $3)` and replace the second group with test/. It will replace the text between `/const-center/` and the last part of the url with `test/`

EDIT: I modified the regex to include the quotes and the attribute name for cases where the URL is inside an HTML attribute such as href

```php
$pattern = '/(href=["\']https:\/\/example.com\/cost-center\/)(.*?)([^\/]+\/?["\'])/';
```

Comment: This seems to work good for the urls without any quotes. But for this one `'href="https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-two/article-3/"'` I think it fails.

Comment: If the URL is inside an HTML attribute such as href, you can modify the regex to include the quotes and the attribute name

Comment: I tried the version with the `href`, it works quite well for urls ending with a slash, but it still does not match if the url ends with a quote and not slash.

Another example: `'href="https://example.com/cost-center/sub-one/sub-two/article-3" data-id="5"'` this would match all the `article-3" data-id="5"'`, but instead it should match till to end of url.

Is there a way to handle both cases?

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the task and your sample data, it doesn't actually matter if/how a URL is quote-wrapped. You merely need to match the leading part of the URL to validate that it IS a URL, then isolate the unwanted substring and replace it.

Notice that my replacement value is only the string `test` and no references to capture groups.  This is because `\K` will forget/release all characters matched up to that point, and `(?= ... )` is a lookahead meaning that it doesn't consume any of the matched characters.

As for isolating the portion of the pattern to be replaced, I am using a negated character class contain forward slashes and whitespaces then a literal forward slash.  That subpattern is may repeat one ore more times (because of the `+` quantifier).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uC9ZR))

```
echo preg_replace('#https://[^/]+/cost-center/\K([^/\s]+/)+(?=article)#', 'test/', $text);
```